# Find the Runner-Up Score

Tags: python, list

In the question of Find the Runner Up Score on Hackerrank.
Given the participants' score sheet for your University Sports Day, you are required to find the runner-up score. You are given  scores. Store them in a list and find the score of the runner-up.

**Input Format**

The first line contains n. The second line contains an array A[] of n integers each separated by a space.

**Output Format**

Print the runner-up score.

**Sample Input**

5

2 3 6 6 5

**Sample Output**

5

As I understand the question. The first line will be the input of **n** and the second line will be the input of an array **A[]** with size **n**.

I found the solution:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    print (sorted(set(arr))[-2])
```

And another solution in another source:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(set(list(arr)))
    ar = len(arr)
    arr = sorted(arr)
    print(arr[ar-2])
```

They both working good but the I found the problem is that the size of an array does not depend on the input of n. For example, if we do

**Sample Input**

5

2 3 6 6 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

Then the output will be 10

**Sample Output**

10

How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?

Comment: There's no problem. The question is posed in a language-agnostic way. In some languages, you may need to know before parsing the second line how many items there will be (or at least, it's convenient to know this ahead of time). That's not the case in Python; `input().split()` will return a list exactly as long as necessary to hold all the array elements.

Comment: @chepner Then we don't need the first-line (input of n) in order for the code to work right?

Comment: Not unless you are supposed to do something specific if `n != len(arr)`.

Comment: Yeah. Just because the question on Hackerrank ask for "The first line contains n. The second line contains an array A[] of n integers each separated by a space". So I think the second line didn't satisfy the question

Comment: Having just solved it, I don't believe you need to care about `n`. None of my test cases seemed to care if I ignored `n`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `arr = set(map(int, input().split()))` to take input as a `SET`. Then sort set using `sorted()` function and print second last element by using element on index **`len(arr)-2`**, or, in case you are using `sorted(arr,reverse = True)` then print via index **1**.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = set(map(int, input().split())) 
    arr = sorted(arr)
    print(arr[len(arr)-2])
```

Comment: Use inline code formatting for better readibility!

Comment: This does not answer `How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?`

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
s=set()
for i in arr:
    s.add(i)
s.remove(max(s))
print(max(s))
```

## with this code we can pass all the test cases easiy

Comment: This does not answer `How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?`

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

res = []

for i in arr:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)

if n==len(arr) and n>=2:
    arr=sorted(res,reverse=True)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i]==arr[0]:
            continue
        else:
            print(arr[i])  
            break

# elif 1 == (n - len(arr)):
#     print("one item is missing")

# elif 1 == n:
#     print("Items should be greater than or equal to 2")

# else:
#     print("{} items are missing".format((n-len(arr))))
```

Comment: Your answer could be significantly improved with a small explanation of what this code does.

Comment: This does not answer `How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?`

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = set(map(int, input().split()))

    sort_arr = sorted(list(arr), reverse=True)
    print(sort_arr[1])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This does not answer `How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?`

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    #convert array into set
    s=set()
    for i in arr:
        s.add(i)
    #remove maximum number 
    s.remove(max(s))
    #print second maximum number
    print(max(s))
```

Comment: This does not answer `How can we fix this problem with the size of an Array in second-line will be the value of n in the first-line?`

Answer (score -1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    arr=sorted(arr,reverse=True)
    k=arr[0]
    for i in arr:
        if(i==k):
           continue
        else:
            print(i)
            break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because `n` is not used anywhere in your code which was the problem that the question was about.